# Logstash displaying weird characters in it's output

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, apache-kafka-streams

While getting the output from a kafka stream, logstash is also displaying other characters. (\u0018, \u0000, \u0002, etc.)

I tried adding a key_deserializer_class to the logstash conf file, but that didn't help much.

```
input {
        kafka {
                bootstrap_servers => "broker1-kafka.net:9092"
                topics => ["TOPIC"]
                group_id => "T-group"
                jaas_path => "/opt/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/config/kafka_client_jaas.conf"
                key_deserializer_class => "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer"
                sasl_mechanism => "SCRAM-SHA-256"
                security_protocol => "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
        }
}
output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }
```

Output

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2019-04-10T06:09:53.918Z,
       "message" => "(TOPIC\u0002U42019-04-10 06:09:47.01739142019-04-10T06:09:53.738000(00000021290065792800\u0002\u0004C1\u0000\u0000\u0002\u001EINC000014418569\u0002\u0010bppmUser\u0002����\v\u0000\u0002\u0010bppmUser\u0002֢��\v\u0002\u0002\u0002\u0002.\u0002\u0018;1000012627;\u0002<AGGAA5V0FEEW7APPOPCYPOR3RPPOLL\u0000\",
      "@version" => "1"
}
```

Is there any way to not get these characters in the output.

Comment: You will probably have to set a deserializer for the `message` field? I noticed that you set, for `input > kafka`, a deserializer for the key.

Comment: @MichaelG.Noll, I tried adding it the input section and the output section of the logstash.conf separately, but both times it showed as an incorrect configuration. Is there any specific way to set the deserializer.

Comment: Sorry, I am not that familiar with logstash.